# Most efficient structure to count unique words in a file [C++]

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, data-structures, word-count

I am trying to create a program to count the unique occurrences of a word in a file and then display them with their counts in alphabetical order.

The key is to do this in the fastest and most efficient way possible.

Try and keep in mind that I am using C++ to write the code, but I am not opposed to a pure theory answer.

Any recommendations?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int> word_count`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/38629/

Comment: What have you done so far? I can't really see any "better" solution than some sort of map and read each word from the file and accumulate the matching position in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using cin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    std::map<std::string, int> word_count;

    while (std::getline(cin, word, ' ')) {
        word_count[word]++;
    }

    typedef std::map<std::string, int>::iterator iter;
    iter end = word_count.end();
    for(iter it = word_count.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        cout << it->first << ", count= " << it->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator[]()` will insert a default-initialized value (in this case, `0`) if the key does not already exist, so there's no reason to check beforehand with `find()`. also, `unordered_map` will probably be faster.

Comment: Updated. Agreed an hash map would be much better if available.

Comment: You need to iterate over them at the end, not as you're going through.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 2 std::set's with some "1-time used words" and "forbidden words: used twice or more times".

So there's a word you processing: cur_word. If forbidden_words contains it, just ignore it, else check if allowed_words contains, delete it from it and add to forbidden_words, else just add it do allowed_words.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_set` may be faster than `std::set` (especially if the file is large).

That's unlikely to make much difference though -- unless you write everything else extremely badly, the job is going to be heavily I/O bound, so most of your work should be put into speeding up the I/O.

How to proceed from there will probably depend on the target OS. For Linux, fast file reading mostly equates to `mmap`. For Windows, you generally want to avoid memory mapped files, and use `ReadFile` with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag.